# ReactiveSwift pipeline count failures after all complete

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-swift

I have a pipeline in [ReactiveSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift) for uploads. I want to make sure that even if one of the uploads fail, the rest will not be interrupted.

After all of them complete with success or failure, I should either return success from the `performUploads` method, or if any have failed, I should return an error, so the next step, the downloads part won't start. Even if there are errors, all uploads should have a chance to upload, they should not be stopped.

Is there a way to figure out if there are any errors after the uploads complete?
See the methods here:

```
let pendingUploadItemsArray: [Items] = ...
func performUploads() -> SignalProducer<(), MyError> {
    return upload(pendingUploadItemsArray)
        .then(doAnything())
}

private func upload(_ items: [Items]) -> SignalProducer<Signal<(), MyError>.Event, Never> {
    let producers = items
        .filter { item in
            return item.readyForUpload
        }
        .map { self.upload($0).materialize() }
    
    return SignalProducer.merge(producers)
}

private func upload(_ item: Item) -> SignalProducer<(), MyError> {
    return internalUploader.upload(item)
        .on(failed: failedToUpload(item),
            value: successfullyUploaded(item))
        .ignoreValues()
}
```

where the `internalUploader` upload method is:

```
func upload(_ item: Item) -> SignalProducer<Any, MyError>
```

And then in another class you would call this uploader:

```
let sync = self.uploader.performUploads()
        .then(startDownloads())
```

The `startDownloads` should only run if all the uploads have completed with success.
Thanks for any insight.

This might be something that should be done in a completely different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm don't know exactly what `successfullyUploaded` and `failedToUpload` are doing in your code, but presumably you're keeping track of successes and failures to provide some kind of live progress UI. This is how I would structure it:

```
struct UploadResult {
    let item: Item
    let error: Error? // nil if the upload succeeded

    var succeeded: Bool { error == nil }
    var failed: Bool { !succeeded }
}

...

static func upload(_ items: [Item]) -> SignalProducer<[UploadResult], Never> {
    SignalProducer(items)
        .filter(\.readyForUpload)
        .flatMap(.merge) { item in
            Self.internalUploader(item)
                .map { UploadResult(item: item, error: nil) }
                .flatMapError { error in
                    SignalProducer(value: UploadResult(item: item, error: error))
                }
        }
        .scan(into: [UploadResult]()) { ( results: inout [UploadResult], nextResult) in
            results.append(nextResult)
        }
}
```

1. I create an `UploadResult` struct that represents an item that has succeeded or failed to upload.
2. In the `upload` function, instead of creating an array of producers and then merging them, I convert the array of items into a signal producer of items with `SignalProducer(items)` and then use `flatMap(.merge)` to merge the uploads into a single signal producer.
3. Instead of using `materialize`, I use `map` to convert successful uploads into an `UploadResult` and I use `flatMapError` to convert failed uploads into an `UploadResult`.
4. I use `scan` to accumulate the results as each upload completes. Each time an upload finishes (either successfully or with an error), `scan` will send an updated array of upload results that can be used to update the UI.

Then you could use it like this:

```
Uploader.upload(someItems)
    .on(value: { resultsSoFar in
        // Update UI here
    })
    .take(last: 1)
    .attempt { results in
        if !results.allSatisfy(\.succeeded) {
            // At least one of the uploads failed, so send an error
            throw MyError()
        }
    }
    .then(startDownloads)
```

1. I use the `on(value:)` operator to update the UI based on the current results. Each time a download succeeds or fails, this closure will be called with the updated results.
2. I use `take(last: 1)` to filter out all intermediate results; it'll only send along the final results when all uploads have completed.
3. I use `attempt` to check if any of the uploads have failed and throw an error if so. This ensures the downloads will only be started if all uploads succeeded.

Hopefully this handles your use case, but let me know in a comment if I missed something about the broader context!

### EDIT

If you only care about dealing with results one at a time rather than as a running array, you can get rid of the `scan` and then replace `take(last: 1)` with `collect`:

```
static func upload(_ items: [Item]) -> SignalProducer<UploadResult, Never> {
    SignalProducer(items)
        .filter(\.readyForUpload)
        .flatMap(.merge) { item in
            Self.internalUploader(item)
                .map { UploadResult(item: item, error: nil) }
                .flatMapError { error in
                    SignalProducer(value: UploadResult(item: item, error: error))
                }
        }
}

...

Uploader.upload(someItems)
    .on(value: { latestResult in
        // Do something with the latest result
    })
    .collect()
    .attempt { results in
        if !results.allSatisfy(\.succeeded) {
            // At least one of the uploads failed, so send an error
            throw MyError()
        }
    }
    .then(startDownloads)
```